# Retroactive tax liability when changing visa types (J-1 to H1-B)

Tags: usa, taxes, h1-visa, j-visa

I recently switched from a J-1 (intern category) visa to a H1-B and am now wondering about tax liability. Whilst on J-1 I was *not* liable for FICA (SS + Medicare) or FUTA, but now that I'm on H1-B I [*am liable*](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Alien-Liability-for-Social-Security-and-Medicare-Taxes-of-Foreign-Teachers,-Foreign-Researchers,-and-Other-Foreign-Professionals):

> **Nonresident aliens**, in general, are also liable for Social Security/Medicare Taxes on wages paid to them for services performed by them in the United States, with certain exceptions based on their nonimmigrant status

Whilst on J-1, it was under this exemption that I did not pay FICA/FUTA taxes.

My question regards this exception. That page says that the exception expires when you switch visa types to one that is liable:

> The exemption does not apply to J-1, or Q-1/Q-2 nonimmigrants who change to an immigration status which is not exempt or to a special protected status.

Does this exemption apply retroactively - will I have to pay FICA/FUTA on wages paid whilst I was on the J-1 visa now that I've switched to H1-B?

Comment: You're never liable for FUTA. It's a tax employers pay, not employees.

Comment: Did you pay the taxes for the exempted period after the change of visa?

Comment: @Maddy No, I did not. The accepted answer is correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You were exempt from FICA for the part of the year you were on J-1; and not exempt for the part of the year you were on H-1b.